# Google Search Console search analytics is not showing any data, even after a week

Tags: google-search-console, analytics, search

In spite of uploading my site's sitemap.xml and submitting the URL to be fetched through Google Webmaster (Fetch), search analytics displays this message:

> Google has not yet processed your traffic.

What are the possible reasons for this happening & what needs to be done?

PS - I don't have a robots.txt

Comment: 1. How old your website ?
2. How many visits you get in a day ?

Comment: As Mani indicated, if people aren't clicking on search results, you might not see any data. Also, you should probably check if you added your site as `http://www.example.com` or  `http://example.com` and verified it. They're considered to be different, so you can try adding both (`www` and `non-www`) and checking back after 24 hours or so. See [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2571221?hl=en) for more.

Answer (score 1):

A week is not much time at all for Google to index a new site. As the message says Google hasn't indexed your site yet and while Google provides the ability through the search console to upload your sitemap.xml file to the queue to crawl your site it still takes time depending on a number of factors which Google doesn't even publish. It can take up to two weeks at times to index a new site when the sitemap.xml file has been uploaded. Unfortunately the only option is to wait as there is no way to speed up Google indexing your site any faster than it already is.